# Bokeh line graph showing no y axis values

Tags: bokeh

I am trying to run a line plot wit some values and and it is showing the dates on the x axis but nothing in the y axis. I tried
p.figure ( y_range=(0,8000)) and it still didn't work.

This is my code

```
source=ColumnDataSource(df_ora)
labels = LabelSet(x='DAY', y='LOAD', text='LOAD', level='glyph',
           x_offset=5, y_offset=25, source=source, render_mode='canvas')
p = figure(title="Transmission Peak Load 
Forecast",x_axis_type="datetime",y_axis_label='Load', plot_width=600, 
plot_height=600)
p.line('DAY', 'LOAD', source=source,line_width=1)
p.axis.ticker=DaysTicker(days=np.arange(1,32))
p.add_layout(Title(text="Date", align="center"), "below")
p.add_layout(labels)
p.circle(x=df_ora['DAY'],y=df_ora['LOAD'],size=5)

# output_notebook()
show(p)
```

So now it shows the days on the bottom, the line plot with the values at the circles, but no range of values in y. I tried to Randge1d(start=0, end=8000), but it still didn't show any numbers in the y axis.

Answer (score 0):

`DaysTicker` assumes the range values will be timestamps, i.e. **milliseconds since epoch**. So giving a range *(0, 8000)* means show the days between 0 and 8000 milliseconds on Jan 1, 1970. There are zero full days in that span.

Comment: You haven't given any indication of either what your data is, or what you are trying to accomplish, so I can't do more that point out the proximate issue.